# How can I pass the result of a python script to the command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

I have written a Python script that collects the magnet link of a torrent I want to download.

How can I then pass this to aria2c in the command line.

This is what I've tried so far, aria2c starts as if it will download but it won´t download a single byte.
I am a complete noob so I apologise and thank you dearly for your help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from pyYify import yify
import os
import subprocess
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://mypiratebay.net/')
searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="home"]/main/section/form/div[1]/input')
searchbox.send_keys('Toy Story 4')
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
torrentlink = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="st"]/span[2]/a')
time.sleep(3)
torrentlink.click()

for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="d"]/a'):
    magnetlink = (a.get_attribute('href'))
    magnetlink = str(magnetlink)

subprocess.call(['aria2c', magnetlink])
```

Comment: Is the `subprocess.call` supposed to be in the `for` loop?

Comment: Tried either way. aria2c starts as if it will download but not a single byte is downloaded. That´s why I would rather pass it into a terminal window if possible.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your asked question, at least partially:

You can grab a **single** output easily using the shell, although I am not sure how well that would work for your needs.  On macos, using, bash:

**test_181_cli.py:**

```
import random
print (random.choice(["a","b","c"]))
```

**test_181_cli.sh**:

```
runmystuff(){
    url=$(python test_181_cli.py)
    printf "\nariac $url:"

    #what you actually want
    #ariac $url
}
```

So then you need to load your bash function definition:

`source test_181_cli.sh` (might be `. test_181_cli.sh` under Linux instead)

then to run it:

```
(venv38) myuser@explore$ runmystuff

ariac b:
(venv38) myuser@explore$ runmystuff

ariac c:
```

Now, as far as the ariac actually not working, I doubt that passing it to the command line would improve things upon subprocess and dealing with multiple urls would anyway be harder.

I suggest you print `print(f":{magnetlink}:")` Note the intentional colons - check if there are no extra blanks and format it appropriately.  Then try running `aria2c <your url>` manually.  You may have all sorts of other issues and subprocess, once you have a correct command line, is probably not the cause for them.  Also, the remark by Daniel Walker is spot on:  your subprocess call belongs in the loop.

Answer (score -2):

You can try these steps:

1. open a command prompt in the same folder
2. type `python file_name`.
3. the output of your program came up.

Comment: Your answer does not address the question, which is to catch the output of a Python script and pass it to another (external) program. Following your steps just allow to run a python script in a regular way.